# Find equivalent capacitance

Tags: voltage, batteries, supercapacitor

How do i calculate no of caps required to replace a battery. If i am given a voltage of battery and capacity of battery and datasheet of required capacitor

Comment: Show us your calculations and tell us why you think your result might be wrong.

Comment: I am new here i did not knew the rules. Anyways i have edited the post.

Comment: @ChanchalAgrawal: Minor points. 'F' or 'farad'. 'A' or 'amp/ampere'. 'V' or 'volt'. This is covered in the SI standard.

Answer (score 2):

One of the advantages of batteries is that they hold the voltage reasonably constant as they discharge and the voltage only drops off suddenly at the end. The voltage on a capacitor, on the other hand, falls continuously during discharge and most rapidly at the start.

[image]

*Figure 1. Capacitor discharge curve through a constant resistance. Source: [Electronics Club](https://electronicsclub.info/capacitance.htm).*

I think your best approach to this problem is to treat it as an energy problem. Assume that you can get all the energy out of the battery and all the energy out of the capacitor even though the voltage is falling.

1. Work out the energy stored in the battery.
2. Find the formula that relates capacitance, voltage and energy. You have the voltage (240 V) and the energy (from 1 above). Now you can work out C.

Post your answers and we'll check them for you.